# Extracting Adam update rates in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to find out and keep track of Adam update rate of

```
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)
```

I followed another post and got the nodes of a graph by

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

In which I found

```
u'Adam/update',
u'Adam/value',
u'Adam',
```

I am assume that either of these three could be the updated learning rate I'm looking for but I don't know how to extract it. Please help

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you've defined an optimizer:

```
optm = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01)
train_step = optm.minimize(L)
```

Now you could reach v_t and m_t with the following code:

```
optm.get_slot(W, 'v')
optm.get_slot(W, 'm')
```

These values are tensors so they are to be evaluated by running a session.

W is some previously defined variable.

Explore more by examing [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py).

Comment: OP is asking for learning rate (lr_t) not for moments estimates. Furthermore you can retrieve all these values directly from your graph, you just need a name, that's all.